# Create part with 45 degree pins

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, schematics, altium

I'm trying to create a model of a thyristor in the Altium 16 schematic library. I can't for the life of me figure out how to rotate a pin at 45 Degrees for the gate. My only options are in increments of 90 degrees. Any ideas?

Comment: Usually what I do for components such as this is draw a line at 45 degrees and then place a straight pin connected to it. To my knowledge there is no way to rotate a pin 45 degrees because that can lead to improper positioning on the grid.

Comment: Very good question though, I wondered the same thing when I first started using Altium

Comment: @DerStrom8 - thanks for the input.  Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]For SCH:
A possible solution is to draw the symbol as you want to see it.  Include lines to mimic the position of pins (at any angle).

Make sure the pin 'lines' end on-grid.  Then place **zero-length** pins at the end of the graphical lines.  Be aware that any text associated with the pins will remain orthogonal.

You can add zero-length pins in the SCHLIB editor in pin-properties.

-Chris

Comment: This is very similar to my response

Comment: @DerStrom8, okay, comment deleted.